# CA1017 ComVisible related errors with VS2010 StyleCop

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, stylecop, comvisible

I have CA1017 error message with StyleCop saying I need to make it ComVisible false.

```
Error   18  CA1017 : Microsoft.Design : 
Because 'NationalInstruments.Labview.FPGA.ModelsimCommunicator.dll' exposes externally 
visible types, mark it with ComVisible(false) at the assembly level and then mark all 
types within the assembly that should be exposed to COM clients with ComVisible(true).
```

Then, I put the code `[assembly: ComVisible(false)]` before the topmost namespace. However, I still got the same error together with other error messages.

```
Error   19  The type or namespace name 'ComVisible' could not be found (are you 
missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    


Error   20  The type or namespace name 'ComVisibleAttribute' could not be found (are
you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It seems that VS2010 also doesn't recognize this name.

[image]

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`ComVisibleAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comvisibleattribute.aspx) is defined in the [`System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9esea608.aspx).

So you either need to:

1. Fully-qualify the attribute's name with its namespace:

   ```
   [assembly: System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(false)]
   ```
2. Add a `using` directive to the top of your source file to import the namespace for that file:

   ```
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   ```

In the future, you should be able to get Visual Studio to warn you about these things. When you see a squiggly line denoting a compiler error, look for the drop-down button that's nearby or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> A menu should appear, indicating possible solutions for the problem. In this case, it would have suggested that you take either option 1 or 2 listed above, and with a single click, would have performed all of the necessary actions for you.

[image]

<sup>(The above amazing animated image was ripped from [here](http://chrispebble.com/Blog/3/5-visual-studio-productivity-tricks-i-use-daily-and-wish-i-had-known-about-years).)</sup>